# Adding values to Combobox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, scenebuilder

I want to add 2 values in my combobox. I added this combobox with scene builder. I used a method to do that but just get an empty combobox.

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> taal;

 @FXML
 public void comboItems(){
//        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Nederlands","Engels");
//        taal = new ComboBox<>();
//        taal.setItems(list);

    taal = new ComboBox<>();
    taal.getItems().addAll("Nederlands","Frans");
    System.out.println(taal.getItems());
    System.out.println("combobox");
}
```

As you can see, I tried through 2 different ways. I get everything on the console.log through the system.out.println, but still get an empty combobox when I run the project.

Here is where I initialized it:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static Controller controller = new Controller();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("student.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Studenten");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1200, 800));


        root.getStylesheets().add("student.css");
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StudentIO.open();
        controller.comboItems();//that combobox is inside a class which is called controller.
        

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you create the node in Scenebuilder/FXML, you should not do ` taal = new ComboBox<>();`.

Comment: work through a tutorial on how to use fxml .. another error (apart from the one already spotted by @Sedrick) is that controllers must be loaded (vs instantiated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making several beginner's error when dealing with FXML.

First of all, if you've defined the `ComboBox` within FXML, then you do not need to create a new one with `new ComboBox()`. When you declare the field in your controller and annotate it with the `@FXML` annotation, JavaFX will create a new instance of the `ComboBox` for you in a process referred to as "injection."

Essentially, JavaFX is taking the `ComboBox` you defined in FXML and "injecting" it into your controller, creating the Java object that you can reference in your code.

In your line `taal = new ComboBox<>();`, you are telling Java to set the `taal` variable to a brand new `ComboBox`, which isn't the same one you are displaying from your FXML layout.

When you add items to `taal` at that point, you **are** adding items to `taal`, but that isn't the `ComboBox` you're seeing on the screen; you no longer have any reference to that particular `ComboBox`.

---

The next issue, as mentioned by kleopatra in her comment, is that you are creating a new `Controller` but your FXML layout knows nothing about it, so it isn't actually "controlling" your layout at all.

There are two possible ways to fix this, depending on how you've defined the controller's relationship with the FXML document.

**Method 1: Controller defined with `fx:controller`**

If you defined the controller in your FXML document, then JavaFX will be making the connection for you. However, like with the `ComboBox`, you are replacing the `Controller` instantiated by JavaFX with a new one in your Java code.

Instead, you should create the reference to the controller in `Main`:

```
private Controller;
```

Then update your `start()` method to set the controller to the one defined in your FXML as loaded by the `FXMLLoader`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("student.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
    scene.getStylesheets().add("student.css");

    // Here you get a reference to the controller from the FXMLLoader
    controller = loader.getController();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Studenten");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene, 1200, 800));

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

**Method 2: No controller defined in FXML**

If you do not use `fx:controller` in your FXML document, you can simply set the controller for the FXMLLoader in your `start()` method. Instead of calling the `loader.getController()` method, use the setter method:

```
loader.setController(controller);
```

Of course, if you are using this method (and wish to refer to the controller going forward), you **will** need to instantiate the `Controller` first so you'd use the line from your original code:

```
private Controller controller = new Controller();
```

Comment: beware: in method1 - you must first load the hierarchy, otherwise the controller you grab is null! in method2 - you still must keep a reference to the created controller (if you want to do anything with it), either before or after loading (which you probably do, but the single line might be a bit confusing to newbies :)